# How to manipulate the Content-Type request header before hitting the Controller component in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

We have recently migrated an RESTful API on running on python to Java, Spring Boot. It is an `GET` endpoint. Once migrated, we are observing "Internal Server Error" being returned by Spring Boot service when the API is called with `Content-Type` request header set as `multipart/form-data`.

However, the Python based implementation works fine without any issues. Below is an excerpt from the exception trace:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.init(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:189)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.getMultiPartStream(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:205)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:224)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:142)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:252)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2921)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2823)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
```

From the internet, I learnt that we need to add the boundary token something like `multipart/form-data; boundary=...`. We wanted to preserve the behaviour of the API consumers that they had with Python. Having that said, is there anyone we can manipulate the request header before the control hits the `@Controller` layer?

Currently the "Internal Server Error" is thrown before by the spring framework itself and control is not returning till the `@Controller` layer.

Is there a way to control the Spring behaviour? We are using Spring version 2.5.6.

Answer (score -1):

At the api level, in the @GetMapping annotation you can provide a MediaType in consumes parameter.
Media type is basically to tell the api what kind of data to expect - json, xml, pdf, etc. You can get detailed info about what media type is from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html)

Comment: Abhinav - It is not about the consumes parameter. My controller accepts the multipart/form-data. This issue here is that the client needs to pass the header along with boundary value, something like multipart/form-data; boundary=..... Unfortunately the consumers are hitting the APIs with out the boundary value